# Pandas Replace NaN with blank/empty string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a Pandas Dataframe as shown below:

```
    1    2       3
 0  a  NaN    read
 1  b    l  unread
 2  c  NaN    read
```

I want to remove the NaN values with an empty string so that it looks like so:

```
    1    2       3
 0  a   ""    read
 1  b    l  unread
 2  c   ""    read
```

Answer (score 396, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
df1 = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
```

This might help. It will replace all NaNs with an empty string.

Comment: what library does `np.nan` come from? I can't use it

Comment: @CaffeineConnoisseur: `import numpy as np`.

Comment: @CaffeineConnoisseur - or just `pd.np.nan` if you don't want to `import numpy` as well.

Comment: This also allows the Dict to be saved as a string in the row of a .csv and then subsequently read back into a DataFrame using the `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(eval(_string_))`

Comment: Also useful to mention the `... inplace=True` option.

Comment: @CaffeineConnoisseur,@elPastor - `pandas 1.0.3` warns of `pandas.np` deprecation in future versions. It was nice having it!

Comment: You can use `float('nan')` instead of `np.nan`.

Comment: You can also use `pd.NA` instead of `pd.np.nan` since 1.0.0

Answer (score 645):

```
df = df.fillna('')
```

This will fill na's (e.g. NaN's) with `''`.

`inplace` is possible but should be avoided as [it makes a copy internally anyway, and it will be deprecated](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529):

```
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
```

To fill only a single column:

```
df.column1 = df.column1.fillna('')
```

One can use `df['column1']` instead of `df.column1`.

Comment: @Mithril - `df[['column1','column2']] = df[['column1','column2']].fillna('')`

Comment: This is giving me `SettingWithCopyWarning`

Comment: @jss367 That's not due to this code, but rather because you've earlier created a partial view of a larger df. Very good answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954986/3427777

Comment: I'm curious as to why `str(np.nan)` doesn't return an empty string, which would seem to me to be the logical result.  I'm sure it has something to do with the inner workings of the sausage factory.  Can anyone point me to a good explanation?

Answer (score 171):

If you are reading the dataframe from a file (say CSV or Excel) then use :

```py
df.read_csv(path , na_filter=False)
```

```py
df.read_excel(path , na_filter=False)
```

This will automatically consider the empty fields as empty strings `''`

---

If you already have the dataframe

```py
df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
```

```py
df = df.fillna('')
```

Comment: na_filter is not available on read_excel() 
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/search.html?q=na_filter&check_keywords=yes&area=default

Comment: i have used it in my application . It does exist but for some reason , they haven't given this argument in the docs . It works nice for me though without errors.

Comment: It works, i'm using it in parse `xl.parse('sheet_name', na_filter=False)`

Comment: I trawled through so many different threads for a fix and this is the only one that worked for my CSV file. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

**Use a formatter, if you only want to format it so that it renders nicely when printed**. Just use the `df.to_string(... formatters` to define custom string-formatting, without needlessly modifying your DataFrame or wasting memory:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'B': [np.nan, 1, np.nan],
    'C': ['read', 'unread', 'read']})
print df.to_string(
    formatters={'B': lambda x: '' if pd.isnull(x) else '{:.0f}'.format(x)})
```

To get:

```
   A B       C
0  a      read
1  b 1  unread
2  c      read
```

Comment: `print df.fillna('')` by itself (without doing `df = df.fillna('')`) doesn't modify the original either. Is there a speed or other advantage to using `to_string`?

Comment: Fair enough, `df.fillna('')` it is!

Comment: @shadowtalker: Not necessarily, it would only be the correct answer if the OP wanted to keep the df in one format (e.g. more computationally-efficient, or saving memory on unnecessary/empty/duplicate strings), yet render it visually in a more pleasing way. Without knowing more about the use-case, we can't say for sure.

Answer (score 7):

Try this,

add `inplace=True`

```
import numpy as np
df.replace(np.NaN, '', inplace=True)
```

Comment: This is not an empty string, `''` and `' '` are not equivalent,  While the first is treated as `False`, the value used above will be treated as `True`.

Answer (score 4):

using `keep_default_na=False`  should help you:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, keep_default_na=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are converting DataFrame to JSON, `NaN` will give error so best solution is in this use case is to replace `NaN` with `None`.
Here is how:

```
df1 = df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with one column of string values with nan.

To remove the nan and fill the empty string:

`df.columnname.replace(np.nan,'',regex = True)`

To remove the nan and fill some values:

`df.columnname.replace(np.nan,'value',regex = True)`

I tried df.iloc also. but it needs the index of the column. so you need to look into the table again. simply the above method reduced one step.