# Trouble reading nested JSON in pandas dateframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm new to pandas and python and am having trouble working through this.  I've got a complex nexted json file I want to load into a pandas dataframe.

I'm using the following code:

```
import json
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

file_str = 'C:\\file.json'

with open(file_str, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as json_file:
   json_work = pd.read_json(json_file, typ='series', orient='columns')

for k, v in json_work.items():
    if v is None:
        json_work[k] = "N/A"

##df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_work)

df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(json_work)

print(df)
```

As it's written I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/.....hack.py", line 18, in <module>
    df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(json_work)
  File "C:\Users\scoe\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json.py", line 708, in json_normalize
    if any([isinstance(x, dict) for x in compat.itervalues(data[0])]):
  File "C:\Users\scoe\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 175, in itervalues
    return iter(obj.values(**kw))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

if I swap these two lines to read

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_work)

##df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(json_work)
```

the process runs successfully but the result does not look like a dataframe.  The output displays like this:

```
---- more lines above this, its a sample of the middle of the output ----
hrCenterName                                          KW App Development & Maint
hrSignatureLevel                                                              1H
hrSignatureLevelTitle                             Level 1 HR Signature Authority
imName                                                                         @
imProvider                                                                   N/A
...                                                                          ...
primaryOfficePhoneExtension                                                  N/A
---- more lines after this ----
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post an output of: `print(type(json_work))`?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: You can replace the loop `for k, v in json_work.items(): if v is None: json_work[k] = "N/A"` with simple `json_work.fillna("N/A")`. **But you don't even want to do that if all you want is to format it so that it renders nicely when printed, just [use the `df.to_string(... formatters` to define custom string-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50978365/202229), without needlessly wasting memory.**

Answer (score 6):

[json_normalize()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) expects `dict or list of dicts`...

try this:

```
with open(file_str, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as json_file:
   json_work = json.load(json_file)

...

df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(json_work)
```

Comment: Thank you for that - I'm going to play around with that.  It may have worked.  The pd data is reference-able now.  It does display a little weird when I print the whole dataframe  but maybe that's an PyCharm setting

SAMPLE 
  alternativeContactName assignedToOrgCode           assignedToOrgName  \
0                    N/A              R501  KW App Development & Maint   

  badgeLabel buildingDescription buildingName  \
0      MITRE          K Building            K

Comment: it was actually the utf-8 encoding that did the trick for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I usually use pandas to read JSON and it works just fine, give it a try:

```
pd.read_json(path)
```