# how to remove the nones from my pivot table in python

Tags: python, pivot-table

Hi I created a pivot table using the below code.

```
table2M = table2M.pivot(index='Shop', columns='Fruit', values='amout_purchased')
```

And I get a table like this one

```
 Fruit |    apple        |   orange  |   banana  
 Shop  |                 |           |                     
:--------------------------------------------- -:    
  A    |   None          |  1/3      |   2/5           
  B    |   1/2           |  None     |   1/9            
  C    |   None          |  None     |   1/3
```

What I would like to do is replace the Nones with a blank space, any idea on how to do this?

```
 Fruit |    apple        |   orange  |   banana  
 Shop  |                 |           |                     
:-------------------------------------------------:    
  A    |                 |  1/3      |   2/5           
  B    |   1/2           |           |   1/9            
  C    |                 |           |   1/3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837998/pandas-replace-nan-with-blank-empty-string.
You could try the answer someone gave there. I mean, not exactly the same, but that's kind of what you are looking for

Comment: this helped thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas Replace NaN with blank/empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837998/pandas-replace-nan-with-blank-empty-string)

Comment: When using Pandas use the function df.fillna(0) to replace all Nones with a 0. df.fillna("") would leave a blank