# How to replace NaN's from a concatenated dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a pandas dataframe. The concatenation of the 1st and 2nd columns results in the 3rd column.

I've tried the df.fillna(") method to cope with the NaN values. However I need to get rid of the NaN's in the concatenated column. While the above method only gets rid of the existing columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = [[], ['arthur','shelby',''], ['michael','','']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'LastName','FullName'])
df['FullName'] = df['Name'].map(str) + ' ' + (df['LastName'].map(str))
df1 = df.fillna("")
print(df1)
```

The output results column contains NaN NaN for the 1st row. However I'm expecting it to be " " " "  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFfZb.png).

Anyway to achieve this???

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837998/pandas-replace-nan-with-blank-empty-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `inplace` in this way:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = [[], ['arthur','shelby',''], ['michael','','']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'LastName','FullName'])
df['FullName'] = df['Name'].map(str) + ' ' + (df['LastName'].map(str))
df.fillna("",inplace=True)
print(df)
```

But the real problem you have is that you are inserting a blank line in data, so you don't have `NaN's` but you have `None`. You should do this (remove in your data the first empty list):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = [['arthur','shelby',''], ['michael','','']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'LastName','FullName'])
df['FullName'] = df['Name'].map(str) + ' ' + (df['LastName'].map(str))
df.fillna("",inplace=True)
print(df)
```

**EDIT** I found your problem, you need to do the fillna before any other manipulation, because you are concatenating two nans converted to string:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = [[], ['arthur','shelby',''], ['michael','','']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'LastName','FullName'])
df.fillna("",inplace=True)
df['FullName'] = df['Name'].map(str) + ' ' + (df['LastName'].map(str))
print(df)
```

Comment: Can you suggest for NaN's as well? The actual problem I'm solving has 1st row components as following 1st column : "", 2nd column:"", result :nan nan

Comment: To summarize for you: I've created the dataframe from an excel file. the 1st and 2nd columns of the 1st row are blank. And the concatentaion of these 2 columns is giving nan nan. It's fine, I just want to replace the nan nan with " " " " in the result column.

Comment: **df.fillna("",inplace=True)** This should replace all your NaN with '' in your df. You need to use inplace=True, so it modifies the DF

Comment: If you don't want to read that first row from excel (because it is blank) you can use read_excel(skiprows=[1]) (In case is the row number 1 you want to skip

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns ={ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'})
df['D'] = df['B].map(str) + ' ' + (df['C'].map(str))
df.fillna(" ", inplace = True)

I've tried this, but still getting nan for places where even one of the column entries is blank in the excel. For instance in the first row, both 'B' and 'C' columns are blank, so I'm getting nan nan. In the 2nd row 'B' has 'somevalue', 'C' is blank so the result that I get is somevalue nan

Comment: No I can't skip any rows, since column 'A' has necessary information.

Comment: I made an EDIT to my answer

Comment: Thanks nacho, the trick was to replace the NaN's before performing the concatenation operation. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Here's two ways of doing that.

1) Check this [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).

```
df.fillna('',inplace=True)
```

2) Additionally, you can use replace method.

```
df = df.replace(numpy.nan, '', regex=True)
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I've tried both of these, result still contains nan nan

Comment: Have you also added **inplace** option?

Comment: Yes, these perfectly work if the resultant column has none none. But does not work for nan nan

Comment: Could you please share your exact output in your question? I want to check it.

Comment: I've added the link of the resultant dataframe output in the question. Please have a look

Comment: Did you put the fillna/replace before the creation of the 'fullname' variable?

Comment: Then you can use simply **replace** method like `replace('NaN NaN', '')`. It should help.