# Fill NaN values with letters

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big dataset, where in one of the columns I want to replace all the NaN values by "ZZZ".
I have already done this:

```
df['code_diag_secund_icd10'].fillna("ZZZ", inplace = True)
```

However, when I do

```
df['code_diag_secund_icd10'].isnull().sum()
```

It gives me the same amount of nan values as before.

Anyone can help me, please?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Try following solution:
[Pandas Replace NaN with blank/empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26838140/4916849)

In your case just paste desired string instead of empty string.

Comment: If this question is a duplicate, then you should flag it as such, no?

Comment: I did df['code_diag_secund_icd9'].replace('ZZZ', np.nan, regex=True), but it still does not replace them. It is as if it did not record the new dataframe with the new values

Answer (score 0):

you can use `replace` function to replace string and coming to find nan value `np.nan` will find the nan value and replace with `ZZZ`

```
import numpy as np
df = df.replace(np.nan, 'ZZZ', regex=True)
```

Comment: Please edit your answer with a textual explanation of the code snippet and explain how it answers the question

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Sure let me add explanation