# replace the existing values to NAN in a given .csv file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hi there I'm a newbie in python learning through notebook, I have given iris dataset through .csv file and asked to replace one of the column values in some particular rows to NaN.I have tried "fillna" functions and "replace" functions but I'm not successful.Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan as NaN
url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data'
iris = pd.read_csv(url)
iris.columns = ['sepal_length','sepal_width','petal_length','petal_width','class']
iris.columns

#iris

iris.petal_length.fillna(np.nan)
iris1=iris.iloc[10:30]
print (iris1)
#bool_series = pd.isnull(iris['petal_length'])
#print (df)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples, and include input and expected output *as text) in the question.

Comment: A csv file is a **text** file and only representations are stored in it. What representation do you expect for NaN values? Just empty fields...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Replace NaN with blank/empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837998/pandas-replace-nan-with-blank-empty-string)

Comment: I already answered below, but @balandongiv linked answer should also answer your question, and it has good examples.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the problem is, that you are not saving the resulting DataFrame from `.fillna()` or `.replace()`. By default, those methods return new DataFrame object. To fix this either save the result to a variable or use `inplace=True` argument in your `replace()` or `fillna()` calls.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use:

This replaces <some_value> with np.nan for the petal_length column

```
irirs.petal_length.replace(<some_value>, np.nan)
```

This will replace the rows where petal_length is equal to <some_value>

```
irirs[irirs.petal_length == <some_value>] = np.nan
```

Comment: @SangeethaPuliad Could you present a desired output?