# nan to empty string python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have written a small python program which writes excel data to csv, I have a few empty cells which are converting as nan in the cvs.

I have been able to convert nan to zero but my requirement is to proce empty string instead zero for nan.

I have tried to use "replace" but it isn't working.

Here my code to write the data

```
# Open th workbook
data = pd.read_excel(excelName, sheet_name, header=None).values


tables = dict()
for header, start_row, end_row in eval(config['headers']):
    
    table = data[start_row-1:end_row, 1:7]
    tables[header] = table
  
with open(join(CurrentDirectory, inputFile), 'w') as file:
    for header in tables:
        for row in tables[header]:
            row = [date, header] + row.tolist()
            row = [np.nan_to_num(x, 0) for x in row]
            file.write(",".join([str(x) for x in row]))
            file.write("\n")
```

so instead of

```
with open(join(CurrentDirectory, inputFile), 'w') as file:
    for header in tables:
        for row in tables[header]:
            row = [date, header] + row.tolist()
            #row = [np.nan_to_num(x, 0) for x in row]
            row = [np.nan, '' , regex=True]
            file.write(",".join([str(x) for x in row]))
            file.write("\n")
```

but I am getting an error, could anybody help me with what am I doing wrong?

```
ERROR: invalid syntax
```

here is what my current csv looks like:

```
A, 2.4, 3212, 0, 343.2234,90
B, 1.4, 0 , 0 , 2839.09, 100
```

and this is how I want it

```
A,2.4,3212,,343.2234,90
B,1.4,,,2839.09,100
```

Comment: `I am getting an error` please paste the error into your question

Comment: `df['colname'].fillna('')`?

Comment: `['' if np.isnan(x) else x for x in row]`

Comment: Note, you should probably be using `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`

Comment: Why not use `pandas` functions such as `pd.read_excel()` and `df.to_csv()`? This enables the use of DataFrame / Series functions such as `.isnull` and `.replace(np.nan, '')`.

Comment: yup, I am using panda to read excel, but it's not a straightforward copy.. reading random rows and appending  headers to differents row which is provided use in config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `np.nan_to_num(x, 0)` you could use the following:

```
row = ['' if np.isnan(x) else x for x in row]
```

If you want to remove the zeros as well (as indicated by your second example) you can simply expand the condition:

```
row = ['' if np.isnan(x) or x == 0 else x for x in row]
```

See [np.isnan](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html)

Comment: TypeEroor: 'float' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

You asked two questions.

1. How to export to csv with empty string instead of `NaN` is answered in the comments. Just use `pandas`.
   Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837998/pandas-replace-nan-with-blank-empty-string) as well.
2. Your invalid syntax error comes from this line

```
row = [np.nan, '' , regex=True]
```

I'm not sure what you were trying to do but you can't write `regex=True` to a `list`.